# Dropdown Options remove from other dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to remove some options from the 2nd dropdown menu based on the first.
I have tried quite a few iterations to get it done but still it is not working.
Kindly provide with solutions
In the below code I need to remove the option from the 2nd dropdown already selected in the 1st one.
I have tried the mentioned HTML & Javascript Code

**HTML**

```
<form>
        Source:
        <select id = "box1" name="a">
            <option>select</option>
            <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
            <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
            <option value="Carrot">Carrot</option>
        </select>   

        Destination:
        <select id="box2" name="b">
            <option>select</option>
            <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
            <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
            <option value="Dice">Dice</option>
            <option value="Carrot">Carrot</option>
         </select>
    </form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    var main = function(){
       $("#box1").change(function(){
       var a = $('#box1 option:selected').val();
       $("#box2 option[value='a']").remove();
       });
    }
    $(document).ready(main);
```

I have tried entering the value as variable a with and without quotes but no effect. Although when i replaced 'a' with a specific value like 'Apple', then the code is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your answer ;)

```js
var main = function(){
  $("#box1").change(function(){
    var a = $('#box1 option:selected').val();
    $("#box2 option[value="+a+"]").hide().siblings().show();
  });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="box1" name="b">
  <option>select</option>
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="Dice">Dice</option>
  <option value="Carrot">Carrot</option>
</select>
<select id="box2" name="b">
  <option>select</option>
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="Dice">Dice</option>
  <option value="Carrot">Carrot</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/uubuumrz/1/

**HTML**

```
<select id="box1">
  <option>111</option>
  <option>222</option>
  <option>333</option>
  <option>444</option>
</select>

<select id="box2">
  <option>999</option>
  <option>222</option>
  <option>888</option>
  <option>444</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#box1').on('change', function(){

    var x=$(this).val();

    $('#box2 option').each(function(){
        if($(this).val()==x){
        $(this).remove();

      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: hi. i test this code before i've written the above code and understand that box1 selected removes from box2 permanently.
but I think he want to see all other options of box2 after change his selected item of box1.
what,s your idea?

Comment: well... maybe but in the question he has mentioned `remove` hence i thought he wants to permanently remove the item

Answer (score 0):

hide().siblings().show()
`instead of`.remove()`

The .remove() permanently removes the selected option in box1 from box2. so if you use .hide() and .show(), it would hide and show. try making these changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#box1').change(function(){
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('#box2').find("option[value="+v+"]").remove(); });
```

Try this simple one